# Can we introduce the mass of a quantum field as an interaction?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

At a free massless Lagrangian 
\begin{equation} L_0 = \frac 1 2 ( \partial \psi)^2 ,\end{equation}
add an interaction term \begin{equation} L_I = \frac 1 2 m^2 \psi^2\end{equation}
where m is small enough to converge its perturbation calculation. From these setup, is it possible to gain the same results as of the free massive Lagrangian? Please point me a book description or some internet site. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and you will find, by summing Feynman diagrams, that the effective propagator is : $ D_{eff}= \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p^2} {m^2} \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p^2} {m^2} \frac{1}{p^2} {m^2} \frac{1}{p^2} + ......= \frac{1}{p^2-m^2}$, as expected.

Comment: @Trimok This should be an answer! You could also highlight the connection to counter-terms (I thought this point of view - the mass as an interaction - is relevant there too).